# Microsoft Project related tag maintenance

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

In order to ensure all Microsoft Project-related tags are consistently named, please could the following changes be made:

- [project-server](/questions/tagged/project-server) (52 questions) rename to [ms-project-server](/questions/tagged/ms-project-server)
- [project-server-2007](/questions/tagged/project-server-2007) (14 questions) rename to [ms-project-server-2007](/questions/tagged/ms-project-server-2007)
- [microsoft-project-vba](/questions/tagged/microsoft-project-vba) (4 questions) rename to [ms-project-vba](/questions/tagged/ms-project-vba)
- [microsoft-project-server](/questions/tagged/microsoft-project-server) (0 questions) delete

This change is being requested to try and inroduce a degree of consistency amongst tags relating to Microsoft Project. Although there is no formally defined hierarchy or relationships between tags, the suggested naming convention ensures that users can follow the logic of relationships like:

ms-project...ms-project-server...ms-project-server-2007

and so on

Comment: If you have any arguments for these changes you should put them in your post to add force to the request.

Comment: @N.N. Consistent naming is good?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Indeed, I just meant that it would be good to state arguments explicitly in the post.

Comment: Do all of the tags really need "ms" in front? This looks a lot like "ms-excel", which I think is rather pointless.

Comment: Removing the ms prefix makes the ms-project tag problematic. The goal of this change was to try and ensure we have a consistent set of tags relating to Microsoft Project, stemming from a base "ms-project" tag. I'm open to other suggestions about what the base tag should be, but "project" on it's own is probably too general.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm all for explicit tags. F.e. `word` can have multiple meanings in programming, also `access`. Microsoft names it's stuff just too ambiguous to let them stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

We should probably make things like [project-server](/questions/tagged/project-server) a synonym of [ms-project-server](/questions/tagged/ms-project-server), that way if someone tries to use the project-server tag they are prompted to use the correct one instead.

Comment: Sounds good to me!